# C# - How to read a text file from GZip

Tags: c#

Here is my problem, i'm trying to make minecraft classic server and i'm using text system to make allow list for each map, problem is text system makes a file for each map and we got around 15k maps in total, so if 1k of players add allow list to their maps, it would be hard to upload / move server to another host. i want to make a zip file in main folder of my software and add each text file to it and also making it readable with system, i want to know how to read a file from GZip, and how to compress files also.

Thanks

Comment: How this c# code is related to the question? Please leave only related code and formulate your question by referencing only an actual code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Details on how to use GZip to compress and decompress. After decompression, you can use the [StreamReader() class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) to read the contents of the file (.NET 4.0).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace zip
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string directoryPath = @"c:\users\public\reports";

            DirectoryInfo directorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);

            foreach (FileInfo fileToCompress in directorySelected.GetFiles())
            {
                Compress(fileToCompress);
            }

            foreach (FileInfo fileToDecompress in directorySelected.GetFiles("*.gz"))
            {
                Decompress(fileToDecompress);
            }
        }

        public static void Compress(FileInfo fileToCompress)
        {
            using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
            {
                if ((File.GetAttributes(fileToCompress.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden & fileToCompress.Extension != ".gz")
                {
                    using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz"))
                    {
                        using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                        {
                            originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                            Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.",
                                fileToCompress.Name, fileToCompress.Length.ToString(), compressedFileStream.Length.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
        {
            using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
            {
                string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
                string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length);

                using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
                {
                    using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
                        Console.WriteLine("Decompressed: {0}", fileToDecompress.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)

Comment: @user2248354 What version of .NET are you on?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Answer (score 15):

Here is my very easy working code. No temporary file

```
using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(reader, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
        using (StreamReader unzip = new StreamReader(zip))
            while(!unzip.EndOfStream)
                ReadLine(unzip.ReadLine());
```

Comment: quite elegant if I don't say so +1

Comment: I don't understand why you're passing `true` in `new GZipStream(...)`?

Comment: You are right, the true param is not usefull because destructed by the end of using

Answer (score 8):

If you want to avoid creating temporary files, you can use this:

```
using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath),
              zippedStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(zippedStream))
    {
        // work with reader
    }
}
```