# Unzip .gz file content is not retained

Tags: c#, gzip, gzipstream

I am trying to unzip .gz file in c# using GZipStream as mentioned in this article

[C# - How to read a text file from GZip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830201/c-sharp-how-to-read-a-text-file-from-gzip)

```
  public static void ExtractGzip(string filePath)
    {
        using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(reader, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
        using (StreamReader unzip = new StreamReader(zip))
            while (!unzip.EndOfStream)
                Console.WriteLine(unzip.ReadLine());
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Length of reader

[image]

Length of zip has an error, but ultimately the ReadLine() has only so much content and nothing more. I copy and paste it to a notepad all I see only the headers.

While there is still more data rows after this header, the endofstream is encountered just after the above.

The content of the .gz file is a .csv file with multiple records.
The files are getting unzipped but only the first row of the csv zipped file(only the headers row) is getting retained in the output unzipped csv file.

I have tried multiple other ways to unzip gz files also including SharpZipLib and SharpCompress and also ZipArchive but none of these work correctly and result in an error, either 'No central directory found' etc.

The same .gz file can be unzipped correctly in python and all the data is retained but not in C#.

What is the cause of this issue, please anyone can throw some light on this would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the data *is* retained. `GZipStream` works fine. How did you determine that only one line is retained? A `csv` is just a text file, nothing more. It doesn't matter if it has one line or many. The code you posted just copies the decompressed contents from eg a `something.cs.gz` file out to a new file, it doesn't deal with records or newlines, it's a simple `Stream.Copy` that copies bytes

Comment: The carriage return may need to be modified so you get more than one line.

Comment: A GZip isn't a ZIP archive. You can't use ZipArchive with a `.gz` file. SharpCompress should work. Are you sure there's only a single line? Perhaps the editor you used to open the file want to see Windows-style line endings (CR+LF)? Both Excel and C# can handle files with just newlines. Most editors can too, and many will autodetect the line endings. In those that don't you can change the line ending setting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is the issue here is that only one row from the .csv is getting retained and the rest of the data does not show up.  Actually after using SharCompress with below code

Comment: How did you determine that? You didn't post any code, text or even a screenshot. GZipStream works. I use it to store several dozens of transaction files daily. It's far more likely that whatever method you used didn't handle newlines correctly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The code is the exact same as posted in my question except that I use the filepath and folderpaths accordingly as my local folders. The code does unzip the .gz file to the specified output directory but when I open the .csv file there is only one row in the unzipped file. I have tried unzipping using Python and it works perfectly fine and all the data is there.

Comment: @jdweng What should be the expected carriage return? Actually the .gz file is supplied by the client and read from a config file, I am supposed to programatically unzip it and perform some functions on the extracted csv file.

Comment: Repeating the same unclear statement in the question and comments won't make it any clearer. You didn't post any code that *reads* the result. You claim there's only one line but are you sure your editor or application isn't showing one long line because it didn't split the lines properly?

Comment: Post actual code that *we* can use to replicate the problem. When you claim that something other people use isn't working, you have to prove it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246858/discussion-between-ravikiran-bheemaiah-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Chatting won't help. Post sample data and code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated question. please take a look

Comment: The carriage return depends on operating system. On windows it should be two characters 0x0D and 0x0A.  If file is only has one you may get edrrors.  You code has "unzip.ReadLine()".  The ReadLine() may be reading the entire file and you think there is only one line.  I would check the length of stream to see how big it is.

Comment: @jdweng updated question please check. The ReadLine() has only so much content and reaches the endofstream and there is no more data to be read.

Comment: @jdweng: `TextReader.ReadLine` handles CR, LF or CRLF, as per the docs: "A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return (0x000d), a line feed (0x000a), a carriage return followed by a line feed, Environment.NewLine, or the end-of-stream marker." I've used it *regularly* on multiple platforms handling a variety of line endings, and never seen that cause an issue.

Comment: If you could provide a sample file, that would really help.

Comment: @JonSkeet How can I share the file?

Comment: DropBox, Google Drive, anything - there are *lots* of ways of sharing files.

Comment: I am afriad I cannot do that as it is a company file. But the unzip works perfectly fine in python that much I can say. Some of the other libraries like ZipArchive and SharpLibZip resulting in 'No central directory found' errors.